# find image source to remove not working to remove in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, internet-explorer

IE 7 seems to ignore this code.  Any ideas?

```
 $("img[src='/v/vspfiles/templates/GFAR NEW NAV/images/Bullet_SubCategory.gif']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely the spaces in the URL. On IE, the test may run against the URL-Encoded version (`GFAR%20NEW%20NAV`).

I would get rid of the spaces and try again.

Comment: I have gone ahead and done that, but I am still having the same problem.  These stupid bullets are not disapearing.  I am thinking of just making them clear 1x1 files, but it is still adding excess space I do not want in IE 7 only

Comment: @user it could also be that the `src` property gets the full path in IE7. Is there no way to use a different approach, e.g. CSS classes, and to select based on that?

Comment: I can set the amount of columns for the image to be placed in.  I ended up setting it to a high number so it runs in a row and turned the image into a blank dot and that seemed to make it work.  it is a bad work around in my opinion, but it shows correctly on the site.